# How to use specified values in each axis of an sns heat map?

Tags: arrays, seaborn

Basically, I need to create a heatmap using seaborn with a set of variables in the y axis, and another set in the x axis. Currently I can only get it to show all variables in both axes, but because I have so many it is very difficult to read.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read('everything.csv')
a = df.drop(columns = ['1', '2', '3', '4'])
b = df.drop(columns = ['5', '6', '7'])

corr = df.corr(method = 'spearman')
sns.heatmap(corr, annot = True)
plt.show()
```

This is essentially what I am working with. I want `a` to be plot on one axis of the heatmap, and `b` on the other. I'm sure its an easy fix for someone more experienced than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the complete correlation matrix, and then subset some rows and columns:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sns.set_style('white')
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
cols_A = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width']
cols_B = ['petal_length', 'petal_width']
corr = iris[cols_A + cols_B].corr()

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5))
sns.heatmap(corr, vmin=-1, vmax=1, cmap='RdYlGn', annot=True, ax=ax1)
sns.heatmap(corr.loc[cols_A, cols_B], vmin=-1, vmax=1, cmap='RdYlGn', annot=True, ax=ax2)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: limit correlation heatmap to some rows/columns]